# CSV File is blank

Tags: powershell, csv

No matter what I do, the output to the CSV file is blank.  Please advise what I am doing wrong.  I just need to find out why the output does not get to the CSV file.

```psh
$servers = Get-Content "C:\temp\servers.txt"
foreach ($Server in $servers) {
    Get-IPAddress -ComputerName $servers -IPV4only
} 
Select-Object Name, IP | Export-CSV c:\temp\final.txt
```

The function `Get-IPAddress` is implemented like this:

```psh
function global:Get-IPAddress {
  #Requires -Version 2.0
  [CmdletBinding()]
  Param (
    [Parameter(Position=1,
              ValueFromPipeline=$true,
              ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
    [String[]]$ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME,
    [Switch]$IPV6only,
    [Switch]$IPV4only
  )#End Param

  Begin {
    Write-Verbose "`n Checking IP Address . . .`n"
    $i = 0
  }#Begin

  Process {
    $ComputerName | ForEach-Object {
      $HostName = $_

      Try {
        $AddressList = @(([net.dns]::GetHostEntry($HostName)).AddressList)
      } Catch {
        "Cannot determine the IP Address on $HostName"
      }

      If ($AddressList.Count -ne 0) {
        $AddressList | ForEach-Object {
          if ($IPV6only) {
            if ($_.AddressFamily -eq "InterNetworkV6") {
              New-Object psobject -Property @{
                IPAddress    = $_.IPAddressToString
                ComputerName = $HostName
              } | Select ComputerName,IPAddress
            }
          }
          if ($IPV4only) {
            if ($_.AddressFamily -eq "InterNetwork") {
              New-Object psobject -Property @{
                IPAddress    = $_.IPAddressToString
                ComputerName = $HostName
              } | Select ComputerName,IPAddress
            }
          }
          if (!($IPV6only -or $IPV4only)) {
            New-Object psobject -Property @{
              IPAddress    = $_.IPAddressToString
              ComputerName = $HostName
            } | Select ComputerName,IPAddress
          }
        }#Foreach-Object(IPAddress)
      }#IF
    }#Foreach-Object(ComputerName)
  }#Process
}#Get-IPAddress
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your snippet, the two statements (the `foreach(...)` construct and the `Select-Object|Export-Csv` expression) are totally disconnected.

Assign the output from the expression inside `foreach` to a variable, and pipe that to `Select-Object` instead

```
$servers = Get-Content "C:\temp\servers.txt"
$Output = foreach ($Server in $Servers)
{
    Get-IPAddress -ComputerName $server -IPV4only |Select IP,@{Name="Name";Expression={$server}}
}
$Output | Select-Object Name, IP | Export-CSV c:\temp\final.txt
```

Comment: @ Ansgar  Sorry guys.. I did not have the post completed.  I have entered all the code now.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Still applies, if you don't assign your new objects to anything, they're gonna get written as output, either to `STDOUT` or to the host/screen if you're running it in an interactive prompt

Answer (score 2):

You don't provide anything to select from (you run `Get-IPAddress` in a `foreach` loop, but the output is not passed into the `Select-Object` cmdlet). Also, your function produces objects with a `ComputerName` property, but you try to select a property `Name`.

Change your code to this:

```psh
Get-Content 'C:\temp\servers.txt' | ForEach-Object {
    Get-IPAddress -ComputerName $servers -IPV4only
} | Select-Object ComputerName, IP | Export-Csv 'c:\temp\final.txt' -NoType
```

As a side note, you may want to make the switches `-IPV4only` and `-IPV6only` mutually exclusive by putting them into different parameter sets:

```psh
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='all')]
Param (
  [Parameter(Position=1,
            ValueFromPipeline=$true,
            ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
  [String[]]$ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME,
  [Parameter(ParameterSetName='v6')]
  [Switch]$IPV6only,
  [Parameter(ParameterSetName='v4')]
  [Switch]$IPV4only
)
```

Comment: Thanks for cleaning up my mess :)